# Google search API to return exactly what google does through a normal search?

Tags: .net, api, search, google-search

I looking to create a web request that returns all the html on the page which takes place when doing a normal google web search through the browser.

e.g if you type in to google ... 'what is the capital of France?'
It returns a box at the top with Paris in it along with the other ten results with basic text.

i am wanting the whole html returned from this page but if do a normal web request google only returns the script that generates these results.

If you right click any where on the page and go to 'inspect element' you can then see a break down of all the DOM elements as html. It is this HTML breakdown that i am wanting to return.

Anybody got any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: I don't understand why this has been down voted, it is a legitimate question. if you do a google search and then 'view page source' you will not see the html elements generated that make up the page. I am looking to get theses elements with attributes and inner html/text

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather use Google's search API and not trying to screen-grab like you describing in your post.

See [.Net (c#) Example using Google Search API](http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2011/03/google-custom-search-in-c.html)